# How to avoid reloading data in each run

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

How can I avoid reloading data each time when I want to check if my script works? I work with spyder and python.

I have to load around 1000 .csv files, it takes just a few seconds but it is unnecessary to repeat this step each time I change a parameter or a name somewhere else in the code.

One simple option is to comment a part of code. What would be a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can use cells in Spyder, which are blocks of code delimited by comments of the form `#%%`. You can evaluate cells with keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (run and advance to the next cell) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (run and stay in the same cell).

This way you can have a cell to load your files and then another cell to do you computations with them, like this

```
#%%
data = load_my_files('my-dir')

#%%
compute(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Should have read the documentation.

Comment: We don't have documentation for this, but we'll have in the future.

Comment: Oh, ok. But you already have syntax formatting using cells. Looks good and helps a lot

Comment: Yeah, that's a feature we borrowed from Matlab and it's very handy.